# Mongo connection stream closes unexpectedly in NodeJS application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, node-mongodb-native

I have a NodeJS application (using the node-mongodb-native driver version 2.1) which does the following:

1. Opens a connection to MongoDB.
2. Queries a collection (batchSize is set to 1000). This query returns about 1,300,000 documents which I have verified myself.
3. Since this is too many documents to fit in the bson response (about 16mb if I recall correctly), I stream my results using the `stream()` function on my cursor object.
4. In batches of 1000 documents, I upload them to my Amazon CloudSearch index.

Everything works as expected - the documents are successfully uploaded to my AWS service and all is fine.

However, as soon as 85,000 documents have been streamed, the stream emits the `end` event. It consistently does this and no errors are thrown. Usually I'd chalk this up to something like a timeout being hit, but the fact that it happens every time 85,000 documents are uploaded and then immediately ends/closes the stream, it makes me think something is up.

My code is as follows:

```
var options = {
    socketTimeoutMS: 120000,
    connectTimeoutMS: 120000,
    keepAlive: 1
};
var url = "www.myMongoAddress.com";
mongo.connect(url, options, function(err, db) {
    var collection = db.collection('myCollection');
    var stream = collection.find({mySearch: 'criteria'}).batchSize(1000).stream();
    var batch = [];    
    var total = 0;

    stream.on('end', function() {
        console.log('stream ended!');
        console.log('processed ' + total + ' docs');
    });

    stream.on('data', function(doc) {
        doc = doc.map(function(d) {
            // Do some transforms on the data here.
        });
        batch.push(doc);

        if (batch.length == 1000 || !stream.hasNext()) {
            stream.pause();
            uploadDocsToAWS(function() {
                stream.resume();
                total += batch.length;
                batch = [];
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Assuming there are more than 85,000 documents that are returned by my query, the stream always ends at 85,000 documents and always takes about 5 minutes (using the Unix `time` utility, the average time is 5 minutes).

Is there anything I can try to help diagnose this problem?

*I have removed some edits as they are no longer applicable*

**Edit1: I've updated the original code to show the connection settings I am now using too, and they don't seem to be helping (connection settings were sourced from: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/reference/connecting/connection-settings/)**

**Edit2: I've simplified the problem a fair bit. Basically, the number of documents I have to process does not matter - my stream will always end prematurely and I'm not sure why**

Comment: Does changing the batch size up or down have any effect on the number of documents processed before end?

Comment: @ry_donahue Hah, yes! I just changed the batch size to 4000 and now it consistently stops at 92000 after about 5 minutes. I'm beginning to think this may be a timeout issue... Any ideas how to increase the timeout/remove it altogether?

Comment: I believe in the options of find you can do: {timeout:false}

But I'll be honest, I'm not convinced it's a timeout. I've seen weird things with CPU usage around resume calls in the past. Unfortunately I never fully resolved those. 

The troubling thing is increasing the the batch 3x didn't increase docs scanned linearly. So timeout is definitely the highest suspect (for me).

Comment: @ry_donahue Yeah I'll give it a go and let you know. Which timeout option will I be looking to change? https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/mongoclient.html is it any of the ones mentioned on there? There are quite a few.

Comment: I think it's just: find({}, {timeout : false}) which is supposed to be false by default but given other db configs I've begged to differ more than once now.

Comment: I'll give that a go.

Comment: @ry_donahue still having problems. See the original question for my updates.

Comment: Can you try: `find({mySearch: 'criteria'}).addCursorFlag('noCursorTimeout', true)...`

Comment: @JohnnyHK Still no luck, unfortunately :( It only processes a portion of the documents before the stream ends.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am missing something your options for your mongoDB connection are

var options = {
    socketTimeoutMS: 120000,
    connectTimeoutMS: 120000,
    keepAlive: 1
};

Which is only 2 minuets. You say your process takes much longer than that? Have you tried increasing these values?

So you may have buffered that X amount of data in the stream during that time hence why you have a longer 'timeout' during the stream than expected.

Comment: Yeah I thought it was a timeout thing but it doesn't matter what those values are unfortunately :( when there are about 30,000 documents left to process the stream ends almost immediately after it has opened and it processes nothing. From about 40000-60000 it will process 4000 before closing the stream. It's very weird and I can't quite figure this out.